# No package confluent-community-2.11 available

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, confluent-platform

I am trying to install kafka on on centOS using this page .
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html
but getting this error

```
No package confluent-community-2.11 available.
```

After running this page command

```
sudo yum clean all &&  sudo yum install confluent-community-2.11
```

It seem no rpm is given here: https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.1/7

Comment: Note: There is nothing stopping you from installing the enterprise one. Even if you don't need the features, then just don't run/configure them, and everything else runs the same

Comment: oh..so we can install enterprise one and use in production without any licence from confluent ??just . feature is enable only once we buy licence !!

Comment: That's correct. And everything that needs a license will work without it for 30 days (like Control Center), so you can try it, and see if it is worth paying for

Answer (score 0):

You need *both* repos added to yum, not just the `5.1/7` (which has some specific additional packages, not the main `confluent-community-2.11` package)

Comment: I am using this setting .[Confluent.dist]
name=Confluent repository (dist)
baseurl=https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.1/7
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.1/archive.key
enabled=1

[Confluent]
name=Confluent repository
baseurl=https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.1/archive.key
enabled=1

Comment: I have followed all the step given on this page .https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html

Comment: let me know if there is any change because it was working 1 week before